# What is the purpose of the version property in the revision component of a NiFi api request?

Tags: http, apache-nifi, minify

I'm creating a NiFi flow using the NiFi api available at https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html .

I'm watching the browser's requests while creating a flow using the UI and I'm noticing each request contains a "revision" component with a **"version"** attribute.

What is the purpose of it and how do I know what version to send with my requests?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The revision concept is used to implement an optimistic locking strategy when updating a component. For example, imagine two users both open the configuration of a processor and start making changes, user1 submits their changes, then user2 submits their changes. The changes made by user2 are no longer accurate as they were based on the state of the processor before user1 made changes. The way this is enforced is that after user1 makes changes, the version of the revision would be incremented on the server, and user2 will submit their changes with previous version and the server will know it is not up to date and reject it.

So long story short, you should be retrieving the component to obtain the current revision/version and sending that back with your changes. If no one else changed the component, then the versions will match and your update succeeds.

Comment: thanks so much. does that mean that if I won't have users making changes then I shouldn't worry about what values I'm sending to the clientId and the version?

Comment: You can either send the current version every time, or you can send the same clientId each time which then means the version doesn't have to match as long as your clientId is the same as the last clientId to modify the component

Comment: I'm now watching the browser's request when creating a template. The snippet request contains the processors, connections and RPGs, including a version for each one. I only created the flow without updating it but the versions are not sent as 0. Is that version different from the one in revision?

Comment: When I instantiate a template, all of the components are created with version of 0 which is what they should be